# exiftool : Warning: [minor] Ignored empty rdf:Seq list for dc:subject - 1159.png for .png images

Tags: linux, exiftool

`Exiftool` is giving this warning when I am setting artist tag for png images.

```
exiftool -artist=hi 1159.png
Warning: [minor] Ignored empty rdf:Seq list for dc:subject - 1159.png
    1 image files updated
```

It is updating the artist tag to `hi` but giving this warning. I don't want to see these warnings. What should I do?

Note: this warning is not comming for `.jpg` images.  I don't understand why it is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely ignore this error. No data is lost. Some software used on this image wrote an empty Subject tag.  To ignore all minor errors, you can add `-m` to your command.

If you want to "fix" this file to avoid the error in the future, you can use this command to rewrite the XMP tags:

```
exiftool -xmp:all= -tagsfromfile @ -xmp:all <FILE>
```

To find any file with this or a similar error, you can use this command:

```
exiftool -if '$warning=~/Ignored empty rdf:Seq/' -warning
```

Comment: The first command works for me. 
it would be great to specify that after it you have to specify the file. `exiftool -xmp:all= -tagsfromfile @ -xmp:all <FILE>`